# Cannot run PHP scripts anymore

Tags: php, wamp

I had been running PHP script successfully for a year or so with WAMP but yesterday i noticed that scripts were not opening/running. When I go to `http://localhost`, the page just *keeps on loading* indefinitely. Of course, there is no errors in the scripts.

**I tried:**

- Re-starting All Services
- Re-installing WAMP
- Even tried easyphp (similar to wamp)
- uninstalled the suspicious softwares

When I tried `telnet localhost 80`, it says **"Connecting to localhost..."** but it never connects.

**Interesting:**

Am able to run script inside PHP Designer (the editor for PHP) but not on browser using WAMP as said before.

**OS:** XP SP2 with Avira Antivirus

**Update:**
Here is my Apache log, but I can't figure out what it says:

```
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:35 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:35 2010] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:35 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 740
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:36 2010] [notice] Child 740: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:36 2010] [notice] Child 740: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:36 2010] [notice] Child 740: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 17 10:27:36 2010] [notice] Child 740: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:15 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:15 2010] [notice] Child 740: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:16 2010] [notice] Child 740: Released the start mutex
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:17 2010] [notice] Child 740: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:17 2010] [notice] Child 740: Child process is exiting
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:18 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2200
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 17 10:31:28 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:20 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:22 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:24 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Released the start mutex
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:25 2010] [notice] Child 2200: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:25 2010] [notice] Child 2200: Child process is exiting
[Wed Feb 17 10:34:26 2010] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:32 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:32 2010] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:32 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3640
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:33 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Child process is running
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:33 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:33 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Feb 17 10:43:33 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Feb 17 10:46:27 2010] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Feb 17 10:46:27 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Feb 17 10:46:28 2010] [notice] Child 3640: Released the start mutex
[Wed Feb 17 10:46:29 2010] [notice] Child 3640: All worker threads have exited.
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off anything running on port 80 ie Skype  (you can run skype after wampserver starts but not before)

I have the same problem also happen to me in Internet explorer are you using that browser?  If you are running certain addons in IE it will cause this issuse such as "AVG safe search" if i recall that was the one causing me problems... but you may want to disable add-ons and try that... try different browsers...

edit: 
one more thing:  check out one of my tutorials on how to edit the host file you may try remove  line 19 and save the file and then restart your server and try localhost again or your local ip 127.0.0.1

http://vzio.com/learn_web-design_development/how-to-customize-localhost-to-anything-you-choose-httpmypage/

Comment: @Jason: thanks i don't use skype and Ie, have tried in all browsers, disabled firewall, port is also not being used by any other program :(

Comment: hmm interesting problem ... have you dont a virus scan in safe mode? what about hijack this?  I would start looking into your system may have something running on it that you don't know about... something is causing this... you also may want to uninstall wampserver and then run ccleaner (www.ccleaner.com)  to clean your registry and clean up your system with that...  you could also try spy-bot search and destroy... 

good luck... let me know if you ever figure it out  maybe its just time for a reinstall of xp?

Comment: Please see the apache log i have added in my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

First check if your apache server is running.
Start->Run->cmd
and then execute command:

netstat -abn

Lookup the result for line like this:

TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       600
[apache.exe]

If you cant find anything listening on port 80 ( no 0.0.0.0:80 line) then your apache is failing to start. To find out why it cant start you should find apache log directory and examine the error.log (may be you have updated your php resently?).
If you find 0.0.0.0:80 listening line but some other software is listening there (do you have IIS running?) then you should remove / reconfigure that softure to free port 80.
If you have apache listening on port 80 but still cant open your site and you cant figure out what is causing the problem via examining apache log files then it my be database problem. Check if your mysql is running and listening using same command but you should be looking for

TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[mysqld-nt.exe]

If you cant find such line then your mysql server is not running - check mysql log files for errors.
If both servers are running and you cant get any output in your browser then check your firewall and antivirus - they may block your requests.
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: mysql is also running corectly and i am able to run mysql queries and client software

Comment: i can see both : apach 0.0.0.0:80 and mysql 0.0.0.0:3306, but still scripts do not run

Comment: Please see the apache log i have added in my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

open up command prompt and confirm:

`telnet localhost 80`

is never connecting, it could be a firewall is dropping packets. Try turning off firewall.

Or you webserver (apache?) is not responding and is hung. Try: stopping apache, confirm apache is no longer running (check task manager), and starting apache.

Comment: i have already tried those telnet and firewall options, but no luck :(

Comment: Please see the apache log i have added in my question, thanks